# business object 14.0 missing library

Tags: excel, vba, business-objects

I think this is a pretty simple question but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I have an excel file with some macros in there to pull the metadata from the BO Universe 4.0. When I run the macro, I get a library error and I noticed that I'm missing this in the VBA references:

> MISSING: Businessobjects 14.0 object library

but I can't seem to get to the right DLL file. Can someone help me here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dlls should be under <program folder>\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86.  I'm not sure of the exact dll, due to the dialog not being resizable.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick diagnosing:

- Do you have SAP BusinessObjects Universe Designer installed?
- Are you sure it's the correct version? Either BI 4.0 or BI 4.1?
- Do you have other (previous) versions of BusinessObjects installed (i.e. XI 3.x, …)?

Open the Registry (*Start* > *Run* > `regedit`) and navigate to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key. See if you can locate the subkey `BusinessObjects Universe` (see screenshot). The key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\BusinessObjects Universe\CurVer` should contain the value `BusinessObjects.Universe.14.0`.

[image]